# How to fill multiple cell in table view with animation bottom to top?

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to add animation for filling the view with color from bottom to top and vice versa. Also to pause animation I am using a timer. 
(Effect of water filling).
The challenge is, I want to fill one cell after the other (Second cell fill once first cell filling is ended and likewise full table view).

Comment: Is the `tableView` scrollable during the animation is in progress?

Comment: No its always disabled

Comment: So you have a not-scrollable tableView with several cells that during the animation takes place are 1)always on screen and 2)not intractable? Also do you have any problems with the animation of filling in 1 cell; or rather with the logic of how to fill-in subsequently all cells one after another?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Actually, I don't have a proper method to give an effect like water filling animation. nither for a single cell. I tried several libraries also like fillableloader.

Comment: As you said, https://github.com/polqf/FillableLoaders looks like the thing that could do the job with the `Wave` animation, but you need to extend it to work with custom views(your cells, 1 at a time). If you could do that, I guess you will manage filling in all cells in no time. Also, you might want to update your question to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: I solve this, In case anyone need then let me know.

Comment: I would recommend posting the solution of the question as an answer and then selecting it as the right answer in this case. Happy coding.

Comment: Actually, its become a mini project, I will try to add on GitHub